# How can I reload app.component.ts on event in pages?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

`app.component.ts` is not listening to the event when it is firing on a particular page. I want to reload my `app.component.ts` as I want to show a different side menu when a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the *ngIf directive:

```html
<sidenav-not-logged-in *ngIf="!userIsLoggedIn()"></sidenav-not-logged-in>
<sidenav-logged-in *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn()"></sidenav-logged-in>
```

If you want to listen to an event (@Output) from a child you have to bind the event to some function in the parent template:

```html
<some-child (someEvent)="someFuntion()"></some-child>
```

Then just implement someFuntion() in the parent component.

For more documentation on types of data sharing between components and an example project see here:
https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/EarlyAngularProjects/tree/master/dataSharing

'Child to Parent with EventEmitter & Output' is about the emitting of events.

I'm willing to take a further look into your problem if you link a stackblitz.